# Handling a Global Exception Specifically for MySQL Connection

Tags: mysql, vb.net, exception

I need to handle all of MySQL Connection error in my whole project, without adding Try Catch clause to every MyConnection.Open() method. My purpose is to change the text of the Exception Error so the users can understand it. What should I do ? Thanks

Comment: Why you don't want to use try? you can do `Try MyConnection.Open() Catch ex As Exception MsgBox("Connection can't be established") End Try`

Comment: Because my project already has so many MyConnection.Open() in it (around 150). Editing each of them won't be effective. Besides, i need to make sure all off the exception will be handled.

Comment: Exceptions need to be handled one by one you cant do a generic thing

Comment: And remember to read [ask] and the [mcve]

Comment: Okay, sure, I'll mind that. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Try Catch` is the recommended way to handle errors as explained by **Microsoft**

You can also easily personalize your message to the user in a `Try Catch`

You said you have many 
`MyConnection.Open()` then this isn't really good programming hence you can use a function like the one bellow.

You can also replace with **CTRL + H** all `MyConnection.Open()` with: `OpenSqlConnection("YourConnectionString")`

I didn't specify since it was obvious for me but you should implement this in a class specially if implementing `using`

This example shows you two methods of handling errors one based on `ConnectionState` and one on the `TypeOf Exception`
Here is a simple example:

```
Private Sub OpenSqlConnection(ByVal connectionString As String)
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Try
            connection.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            If connection.State = ConnectionState.Broken Then
                MsgBox("The SQL connection is broken!")
            ElseIf connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                MsgBox("The connection was closed!")
            ElseIf TypeOf ex Is SqlException Then
                MsgBox("There is an SQL exception")
            ElseIf TypeOf ex Is InvalidOperationException Then
                MsgBox("There was an invalid operation")
            End If
        Finally
            'Clean up code
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
```

Make sure to check [Try Catch MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973849.aspx) Also you can check the [SqlConnection.Open()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open(v=vs.110).aspx) to see the types of errors handled

Comment: I see, that way will sums it up way more effectively. Thanks !

Comment: @JeffJo Please make sure you take the time to accept the answer if this helped you

Comment: I don't think this does what you think it does!  Once the code leaves the `Using` block, the connection will be closed and disposed, hence, unusable outside the method.

Comment: I'll mind that. thanks @ChrisDunaway

Answer (score 0):

You also can use `OpenSqlConnection` from @Mederic to new Class (right click project -> add -> class) and using it as instance for every form in your project `Dim dbms as New classDatabase`

Add a new class "classDatabase" in your project, code:

```
Public Class ClassDatabase
    ..
    Public Sub OpenSqlConnection(ByVal connectionString As String)
            Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
                Try
                    connection.Open()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    If connection.State = ConnectionState.Broken Then
                        MsgBox("The SQL connection is broken!")
                    ElseIf connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                        MsgBox("The connection was closed!")
                    ElseIf TypeOf ex Is SqlException Then
                        MsgBox("There is an SQL exception")
                    ElseIf TypeOf ex Is InvalidOperationException Then
                        MsgBox("There was an invalid operation")
                    End If
                Finally
                    'Clean up code
                End Try
            End Using
        End Sub
    ..
End Class
```

Here is the implementation for ClassDatabase in your project Form:

```
Public Class Form1  
    Private dbms As New ClassDatabase
    ..
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        dbms.OpenSqlConnection("connectionstring")
    End Sub
    ..
End Class
```

this code not complete test make sure you handle all variable needed

Comment: Again, once the code leaves the Using block, the connection will be closed and disposed, hence, unusable outside the method.  Plus it is a bad idea to have a global connection object.  It is better to open the connect when it is needed, execute the query, and then close and dispose the connection.